# PHPUnit Placeholder for empty tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I like to have empty functions on occasion for placeholders (primarily empty constructors, since it helps avoid accidental duplication of constructors since my team knows there must always be one somewhere).

I also like to have at least one test for every method of a class (largely because it is a nice easy rule to hold my team against).

My question is simple: what should we put in these empty test methods to prevent the "no tests" warning.

We could just do $this->assertTrue(true), which I know will work just fine. However, I was wondering if there was anything a touch more official and proper (preferably something which makes it so the method isn't counted in the number of tests run, artificially inflating it a bit).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this :

```
/**
 * @covers Controllers\AdminController::authenticate
 * @todo   Implement testAuthenticate().
 */
public function testAuthenticate()
{
    // Remove the following lines when you implement this test.
    $this->markTestIncomplete(
      'This test has not been implemented yet.'
    );
}
```

Comment: That's more along the lines of what I'm looking for and could work. However, the test isn't really incomplete... it tests everything it needs to test (which is nothing) because the function itself does absolutely nothing.

Comment: I also realized that causes it to skip anything which @depends on that, so it doesn't really work for my use case.

Comment: it is however [exactly what PHPUnit recommends you do](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html). How can a test that depends on another truly depend on it, if it isn't yet implemented? Sounds like your dependencies mean something different than intended.

Comment: First, I agree with mpm. If you insist on testing a function that does nothing, then you could verify that the return is null. Less then ideal but makes more sense than $this->assertTrue(true), which says nothing at all about the tested method.

Comment: I agree it is a bit wonky to have a dependency on a constructor. However, in a team environment, it's better if we set this up now so if something is added to the constructor, you just have to add a proper test and away you go, instead of having to go back and add in all of the dependencies then. It is a bit silly, but also helps with consistency.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because in most cases it is. It does have a weird implication because of how I'm laying out stuff, but that's because I'm purposely doing something a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

You try a reflection class on the function and ensure that the method is there.  Then the test could simply be that the method exists (empty or not), which will pass without a warning.

```
class MethodExistsTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $FOO;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->FOO = new \FOO();
    }

    /**
     * @covers \FOO::Bar
     */
    public function testEmptyMethodBarExists()
    {
        $ReflectionObject = new \ReflectionObject($this->FOO);
        $this->assertTrue($ReflectionObject->getMethod('Bar'));
    }

    /**
     * @covers \FOO::__construct
     */
    public function testConstructorExists()
    {
        $ReflectionObject = new \ReflectionObject($this->FOO);
        $this->assertNotNull($ReflectionObject->getConstructor());
    }
}
```